# C#: How to detect if running as service from library?

Tags: c#, service

As a library I don't know the name of service. For now I would like to avoid to send variable e.g. isService from main app to library.

Also I come across to Environment.UserInteractive property but I read that is not 100%. You can check "Allow service to interact with desktop" for that service and than UserInteractive = true.

EDIT: Sorry for the missing details. Language is C#. OS is Windows. Library is some-kind of a proxy between different apps. So it can be used from service or from desktop app. I need to know if it is running as a service because I have to disable some code/logic in that case.

Comment: Language? OS? I'd guess Windows/C#, but you tell us.

Comment: Please add more details about technologies, language and context.

Comment: It really does make more sense to let your host application let you know about the things you need to know about your environment (And no, it shouldn't just be a `bool` of service/desktop. If you need specific functionality, have your host provide information about *that*). And e.g. raise events rather than yourself creating pop-up windows, as an example.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Can not do that, because I don't know all usecases of my library and for now I don't want to change initialization.

Comment: @trubar - **exactly**. At the moment, you're thinking about service/desktop. What about hosted in asp.net? What about usage from console? Either of those could be more "service like" or more "desktop like" for whatever functionality you're planning to use conditionally. So try to write *host agnostic* code for the most part and let the host supply the host specific parts (not to say that you may not also have sensible defaults you make *available* from your library for desktop or service environments)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbelieve I agree that this would be foolproof and ready for all types of environments. But I don't have the luxury to just change initialization. First I have to research if this can be automated.

Comment: The only alternative is to use heuristics to *guess* the answer. But some heuristics that used to work no longer do and any heuristic that works now is not guaranteed to in the future. For me, that's a bad basis for writing any code. And even if they get the answer right, it may turn out that e.g. some desktop application *really needs you* to treat it the same as you would a service (if for no other reason that you're trying to debug an issue in a service and it's temporarily easier to write a forms app to try to reproduce the issue)

Comment: It's also an obstacle to *testing* your code - how do you ensure that your unit tests cover both desktop and service behaviours?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I just have to log that some functionality wont work if in service mode. Soo for now testing will be simple.

Comment: So you want your library to work differently based on whether or not I click the exe from my desktop or via the servicemanager? That indeed looks like a testing nightmare. Does that mean your write an extra service to host your unit-tests for your library?

Comment: Please lets focus on my question. 

After I implement this I will open another question about unit testing service. :) Ok? :)